# Automatically generate Complex Type In Code First Approach

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework

Is there any tool available that will generate complex type classes for Code first approach in Entity Framework?

Comment: this article will help you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj593170(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use this tool, found at code project.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892233/POCO-Generator